# COUNT(*) inaccurate on linked server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I am running a query over a linked server in SQL Server to Oracle using the `OraOLEDB.Oracle` provider.

When I run this query, I get a data set of 11,990 rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY([ORA_LINK], 'SELECT * FROM DB1.MY_TABLE');
```

However, this `COUNT(*)` query returns a value of **200**, not 11,990:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM OPENQUERY([ORA_LINK], 'SELECT * FROM DB1.MY_TABLE');
```

Is there something in the linked server or provider settings limiting this?

*UPDATE*: If I access the table directly, I get the correct count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [ORA_LINK]..[DB1].[MY_TABLE]
```

So seems the issue is with the usage of `OPENQUERY`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it is related with default [fetchsize](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e17726/using.htm#OLEDB150)

> FetchSize - specifies the number of rows the provider will fetch at a time (fetch array). It must be set on the basis of data size and the response time of the network. If the value is set too high, then this could result in more wait time during the execution of the query. If the value is set too low, then this could result in many more round trips to the database. Valid values are 1 to 429,496, and 296. The default is 100.

---

1 Materialzing it on SQL Server side

```
SELECT *
INTO #tmp
FROM OPENQUERY([ORA_LINK], 'SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE');

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp;
```

2 Runing `COUNT(*)` or Oracle side;

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([ORA_LINK], 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE');
```

Comment: The workarounds are good, but fetch size doesn’t explain the problem.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I am also really curious what could cause it, it is interesting issue. My idea was that author could change default fetchsize and get different value that will match it.